# Get XML tag values through shell script

Tags: xml, shell, unix, sed, awk

I need to fetch username and password values from sample XML tags

```
<CommCellUser userName="~!@#$%^&*()_+`1=- 23)()();';" password="":>?<,./;'|}{[]  ><:"/" </CommCellUser>
```

The value will be in double quotes. That value may contain double quotes and any other special characters including spaces .

```
comm_cell_line=`grep "CommCellUser" /filename | head -1`
userName=`echo "$comm_cell_line" | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d"\"" -f2`
passwd=`echo "$comm_cell_line" | awk '{print $3}' | cut -d"\"" -f2`
```

Fetching like this miss so many cases. Because it may contain spaces and special characters in value.

Please help .

Comment: sample xml tags :<CommCellUser userName="~!@#$%^&*()_+`1=- 23)()();';" password="":>?<,./;'|}{[]  ><:"/" </CommCellUser>

Comment: edit your post to format your script correctly and provide some sample input and the expected output from that input.

Comment: wrt the statment that "The value will be in double quotes. That value may contain edouble quotes": how can text be delimited by a character and yet contain that character? It can't unless there's some escaping rule applied to that character within the text, e.g. `"foo\"bar"` or `"foo""bar"` or .... so you need to tell us what that escaping rule is and show an example.

Comment: Since i am reading it from a file ,The user name and password may set to anything . In my last post ,By using your method we set the value for it ,Which can contain all the characters . The rule is tag UserName="(Can contain any thing within this quotes)" for password also same .

Comment: If a quoted-delimited string can contain quotes then there is no solution as there is no way to tell where the string ends.

Comment: for example, given the text `"the"quick"dog"`, is that 3 strings `"the"`, `quick`, and `"dog"` or one string `"the"quick"dog"` or something else?

Comment: First off the xml you show violates standards for encoding special characters.  So we cannot give you an answer - as Ed points out.  see http://yellowduckguy.wordpress.com/2008/05/10/xml-special-characters-conversion-list/

Answer (score 0):

The following solution encodes the strings passed to the *userName* and *password* attributes, so that the XML string is considered valid.

```
#!/bin/bash

XML="<CommCellUser userName='~!@#$%^&amp;*()_+``1=- 23)()();&#39;;' password='&quot;:&gt;?&lt;,./;&#39;|}{[]  &gt;&lt;:&quot;/'></CommCellUser>"

USER=`echo $XML | xmllint --xpath "string(/CommCellUser/@userName)" -`
PASS=`echo $XML | xmllint --xpath "string(/CommCellUser/@password)" -`

echo username=$USER
echo password=$PASS
```

Produces the following output:

```
username=~!@#$%^&*()_+1=- 23)()();';
password=":>?<,./;'|}{[] ><:"/
```

Since you're parsing the data you could assume that the incoming data is valid. The xmllint command could be used to enforce this check.

Notes:

- Wikipedia has more information on [XML character escaping and encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML#Characters_and_escaping). Simpler to read compared to the XML specs :-)

Answer (score 0):

i hope that the password value in your example is a typo. otherwise your xml may have problem. so I removed the double quote from the password value. take a look the test below, grep is your friend to get things from text:

```
kent$  echo $comm_cell_line                                           
<CommCellUser userName="~!@#$%^&*()_+`1=- 23)()();';" password="quote removed:>?<,./;'|}{[]  ><:"/" </CommCellUser>

kent$  userName=$(grep -Po '(?<=userName=")[^"]*' <<<$comm_cell_line )

kent$  pwd=$(grep -Po '(?<=password=")[^"]*' <<<$comm_cell_line )     

kent$  echo $userName                                                 
~!@#$%^&*()_+`1=- 23)()();';

kent$  echo $pwd     
quote removed:>?<,./;'|}{[]  ><:
```